# AWS Lambda postgres query is timing out

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
var pg = require("pg");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

var conn = "blanked out for SO";
var client = new pg.Client(conn);
client.connect();

userName = event.userName;

var client = new pg.Client(conn);
client.connect();

var query = client.query({
    text: 'SELECT address from users where userName= $1',
    values: [userName]
});
query.on("row", function (row, result) {
   result.addRow(row);
});

query.on("end", function (result) {
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    client.end();
    context.done(null, jsonObj);
   });
};
```

Im using the above code to return one row from a table. I execute locally using lambda-local and have uploaded to execute in AWS, i keep getting a time out from AWS/local. I believe it has got to do with the query.on, if I add a   context.done(null,"success") to the end just before the last brace it will return a success. 
How do i get it to return the row from the query?

Comment: On an unrelated (SQL injection) note: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: updated to remove SQL Injection, still dont know why it wont return a record though

Answer (score 3):

schoolboy error, Turns out I need to allow AWS traffic through to my postgres server via the security group.